# Launch a pdf as a resource

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf, embedded-resource

I have a WinForms application and I have made a "help file" as a PDF. I would like to add the PDF to the application as a resource, then open it when the user clicks a button (using the user's default PDF viewer). Is this possible?

Comment: **release** the embedded resource to temp file then `Process.Start`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the pdf file with "Add Existing Item ..." to your project. Then set the properties of it to "Resource" and "Do not Copy"

Now follow the answer from the duplicate link to open the pdf from resources.